# Word for discrete time-segments of a user's activity (can't use 'session')

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a clump of user actions, such as clicking a link or downloading a file.  Previously, the word *session* was used, but that is already used by business partners to refer to a distinct grouping of actions.

> Most users' ____________ are 8-9 minutes long, but some users have ____________ that are 6 hours long.

I would prefer a word that specifically refers to people doing stuff, but otherwise could settle for a generic globbing word like *interval*, *cluster*, or *series*.

Comment: How about sub-session?

Comment: _Transaction_, maybe? It's a set of actions that normally is seen as a set that either succeeds or fails completely before continuing.

Comment: Are the actions in the sequence related? Are they related to accomplishing a single task? In that case, consider the word *task*. If they are unrelated then this is just a *sequence of actions*.

Comment: @Drew, They are only related in time, not necessarily in task.  For example, if a user lands on a "main page" and opens a bunch of links on that page in new tabs (weather, email, news, etc), we want to clump what the user does in that burst of activity together.  This might happen a few times a day or even once a day, and we can compare "clumps" over time.

Comment: Engagement, Occupation?

Comment: How about "moment?"

Comment: You could use ***interactions***

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word, "activities" would work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call a "clump" of user actions a "block."  *A block of time* is a familiar phrase.